# Efficiently relate two large shapefiles for use in Python script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, shapefile, spatial-join

I have a large National Land Use Code polygon shapefile for the San Diego area as well as a large point shapefile representing the center of each pixel from the Land Use Code raster for the same area.

The point shapefile is about 213,000 records and the polygon shapefile is about 170,000 records.  I'd like to spatially relate the points to the polygons so that the output will have each polygon and the points that fall within each polygon and will then use it in a Python script making use of a GIS library that can read and analyze shapefiles.

Since the two shapefiles I am joining are so large and the join type is a 1-to-many the resulting shapefile comes out to around 41gb when stored within a geodatabase, and won't even finish writing out if I don't store it in a geodatabase and just a folder.

Is there any way to spatially relate these two files in a more efficient way? I have attached a snapshot of the two files overlaid on top of each other.  Some polygons only have one relationship, while others have tens and hundreds of relationships.

[image]

Comment: I recommend exporting your data to a file geodatabase because The spatial indexes are automatically managed/updated and the max size of each layer is greater. Of course, install and enable 64 bit processing to unlock more memory.

Comment: Shapefile size limit is 2gb just for your info

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do and exactly what you have tried. What tool and settings are you using? If you are spatially joining points to polygons maybe you are producing multiple polygon geometries for each overlapping point. You cant store shapefiles in a file geodatabase.

Comment: 1) Don't use shapefiles for this; Convert both to file geodatabase or PostgreSQL. 2) When you use Intersect, specify the ONLY_FID option, which will prevent massive attribute joining;  The resulting table will be large but not very large. 3) If you use PostgreSQL, you can join via PostGIS geometry and better control the all/almost-nothing attribute map, but you should carefully choose which columns to keep (e.g., codes not names)

Comment: Run near on points vs polygons. 20 seconds? Do summary statistics on near fid. 20 seconds? Transfer results to polygons through join.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to run a spatial join setting the [field mapping](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) to *join*. This will create an output where each polygon has a comma separated list of point IDs.

Comment: Thanks, this should work but some of the polygons have SO many points within them that it exceeds the character limit in the output cell of the attribute table.

Comment: @Scott4993 if that's the case then you are looking at a relational approach where you have your polygon layer and a standalone non-spatial table which is listing the points in the polygon. That would be the more sensible way of storing that vast amount of information. A simple model iterating through each polygon could generate that.

Comment: Or maybe a spatial join of polygon to points that would pass the polygon ID to each point, a few minutes of processing and that would be it, export table and then build the relationship.